# How to loop over a getattr in ponyorm select?

Tags: python, ponyorm

I see that the below is possible:

```
attr_name = 'name'
param_value = 'John'
select(getattr(c, attr_name) for c in Customer)
```

However for this I get an error:

```
attrs = ['id', 'name']
select((getattr(c, attr) if for attr in attr_name) for c in Customer)
```

Any ideas if this is possible to do within the select statement? (ie not pulling everything and then only pulling the columns I care about)

This is almost the same usecase as the one referenced here:

https://docs.ponyorm.org/api_reference.html#getattr

Comment: Out of curiosity, what do you want to achieve with this?

Answer (score 0):

This one does the trick, but it's not within the `select` statement:

```
attrs = ['id', 'name']
for attr in attrs:
    select(getattr(c, attr) for c in Customer)
```

Comment: yeah that's what I ultimately chose. Do you know if there are any speed effects from doing it the way you describe? for example compared to having `select((c.id, c.name) for c in Customer)`?

Comment: oh also you'd always have to pull in `c.id` in case there are duplicate names